# PHP cURL post and send url problems

Tags: php, redirect, post, curl, payment-gateway

i have a problem when i try to request from my own script eg. testscript.php to a 3parts domain when i post the data to like a `<form>` inputs

my code look like this

```
$urltopost = 'https://secure.quickpay.dk/form/';

$opts = array( 
  CURLOPT_POST => true,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post_string,
  CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,
  CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true
);


$curl_connection = curl_init($urltopost); 
curl_setopt_array($curl_connection, $opts ); 
$output = (string) curl_exec($curl_connection); 
curl_close($curl_connection);
```

My problem is now when i try to make a post, its still stay on my pages testscript.php and not send me to my `$urltopost` and that i need it to, becures i use a payment gateway and want to PHP to handle the request and not HTML `<form>` inputs

my curl_getinfo() look like this

```
Array ( 
    [url] => https://secure.quickpay.dk/form/ 
    [content_type] => text/html 
    [http_code] => 200 
    [header_size] => 357 
    [request_size] => 63 
    [filetime] => -1 
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0 
    [redirect_count] => 0 
    [total_time] => 0.259001 
    [namelookup_time] => 0.000702 
    [connect_time] => 0.02734 
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.134342 
    [size_upload] => 0 
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0 
    [speed_upload] => 0 
    [download_content_length] => -1 
    [upload_content_length] => 0 
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.258987 
    [redirect_time] => 0 
    [certinfo] => Array ( ) 
    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

Comment: have you tried `print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection ))` ?

Comment: Using `curl` will not redirect you to a page. It will make the HTTP request from your server.

Comment: Hmm, okay, i think its will be redirect, but how can i make a "auto post" call in PHP whitout the user need a secound pages load?

Comment: it has been some time since i last usedthis, but i rememebr that accessing https adresses was probematic due to the authentication...

Comment: are you refering to header location? a simple redirect?

Comment: ianace: if i use header('location: url'); so the post data will not follow :/